# Rails 6 Actioncable user is typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I have created a chat app with rails 6 and I'm using actionable along with stimulus in order to broadcast the messages and notifications in realtime. The setup I have thus far works just fine!

Now I'm trying to add `a user is typing` feature as well, but I'm having trouble implementing it! The ideas is to create a `typing_channel` with a `is_typing` method in order to broadcast the event and then show the output data via the received method inside the stimulus controller.

With all the previous implementations I call the broadcast action after the creation of a message and then I show the data via the received method inside the stimulus controller.
But for the `is_typing` feature the precess is different since I will not be creating a message this time.
So my main issue here is, how to trigger the broadcast event when I start typing inside the form??

```
class TypingChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stop_all_streams
    stream_from "typing_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end

  def is_typing(data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "typing_channel", typing: data['typing'], user: current_user
  end
end
```

Th stimulus controller:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
import consumer from "../channels/consumer"

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ['status'];
    connect() {
        this.channel = consumer.subscriptions.create('TypingChannel', {
            connected: this._connected.bind(this),
            disconnected: this._disconnected.bind(this),
            received: this._received.bind(this),
        });
    }

    disconnect() {
        consumer.subscriptions.remove(this.subscription)
    }

    _connected() {
    }

    _disconnected() {

    }

    _received() {
    alert("receiving data")
    }
}
```

And this is the form that I create the messages and I want to show when a user is typing feature:

```
<div data-controller="typing" data-target="typing.status" id="user_is_typing"></div>

<%= simple_form_for @message, url: consumer_create_conversation_message_path, html: { data: { action: "ajax:success->channel#clearMessage" }, method: :post, remote: true, id: :chat_form } do |f| %>
<%= f.input :body, label: false, placeholder: "Type your message here", :input_html => { id:"text_send", :rows => 2, class: "text_area_none" } %>
<%= button_tag type: 'submit', id:"button", class: "btn btn-primary btn-m fa-pull-right"  do %><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i><% end %>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you use a keyup event and then count the number of characters in the text box to make sure more than 0?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sam! Yes I could do that but how would I also trigger the actionable broadcast event?

Comment: I forgot how to set this up, but I use a gem called [Noticed](https://github.com/excid3/noticed) to do some of that backend for me. Not sure if it will help in this instance.